# Can I use braintree sdk with python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, braintree

The braintree git repo says in the [README](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_python) it is compatible with Python 3.4 but `caniusepython3` tells me it is not.

Can I safely use it?

```
$ caniusepython3 -r requirements.txt 
Finding and checking dependencies ...
[WARNING] Stale overrides: {'reportlab'}

You need 1 project to transition to Python 3.
Of that 1 project, 1 has no direct dependencies blocking its transition:

    braintree
$
$ more requirements.txt 
braintree==3.24.0
requests==2.9.1
```

Answer (score 2):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The Braintree Python library is compatible with Python 3.3 and higher.

`caniusepython3` uses a [list of classifiers](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=list_classifiers) from PyPi to determine if a project is Python 3 compatible. Since [braintree has no classifiers listed on PyPi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/braintree/3.24.0), it is not listed as 
Python 3 compatible.

The only dependency of the Braintree library is `requests`, which is listed as compatible.

We'll work on updating PyPI to reflect the compatibility.